# Quiver plot wont show up on all subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been trying to plot multiply images using pcolormesh on subplots. It all works fine but the quiver plot only shows up on the last image and not the others. I've been trying to search around for examples of making quiver plots on subplots, but have found nothing. Does anyone have anyone have any idea why the quiver plot is only showing up on the last plot? Below is my the plotting section of my code.

```
plt.clf()
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.0)
fig.set_size_inches(14,6)
axes[1].set_yticklabels(axes[1].get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
for ax in range(len(axes)):
    plot = axes[ax].pcolormesh(X[ax], Y[ax], image[ax], cmap=plt.cm.gist_heat, norm=LogNorm(vmin=cbar_min, vmax=cbar_max))
    axes[ax].streamplot(X[ax], Y[ax], magx[ax], magy[ax])
    Q = plt.quiver(X_vel[ax], Y_vel[ax], velx[ax], vely[ax])
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to change

```
Q = plt.quiver(X_vel[ax], Y_vel[ax], velx[ax], vely[ax])
```

to :

```
Q = axes[ax].quiver(X_vel[ax], Y_vel[ax], velx[ax], vely[ax])
```

Otherwise it only applies to the last ax in the loop